# What is Mike's formula for naming software packages?

Tags: pattern, knowledge

Mike works for the marketing department of a software company.
His job is to come up with names for new products, and he has devised a formula for doing so.

For example, when the company developed a new Payroll System, Mike named it 'Ps'. When they announced their Customer Relationship Management and Bug Tracking Management System products, Mike named them 'Chromi' and 'Bratanmiksie' respectively.

The company is about to announce their new Online Payment Processing Gateway. What will Mike name it, and why?

Comment: Are you the Mike from the question?  If so, I have to disapprove of this naming convention...

Comment: He's just trying to see if he can automate his job via PSE, @DavidStarkey 

Comment: @DavidStarkey"Mike works for the *marketing department*" ... so no; HELL NO!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

He names it

> **OSCPAPPAPGOL** (**O**nline **P**ayment **P**rocessing **G**ateway = *Osc*ar *Pap*a *Pap*a *Gol*f)

Because the naming convention:

> Uses the phonetic alphabet, more specifically:
>
>  1. Use the initials of the software package to get the equivalent [phonetic alphabet's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet) phonics
>  2. If the number of words in the software package's name is $n$, take $n-1$ letters from each phonic
>
>  - **P**ayroll **S**ystem - *P*apa *S*ierra - **Ps** (2 words in the software package name, hence 1 letter from each phonic)
>  - **C**ustomer **R**elationship **M**anagement - *Ch*arlie *Ro*meo *Mi*ke - **Chromi** (3 words in the software package name, hence 2 letters from each phonic)
>  - **B**ug **T**racking **M**anagement **S**ystem - *Bra*vo *Tan*go *Mik*e *Sie*rra - **Bratanmiksie** (4 words in the software package name, hence 3 letters from each phonic)

Comment: Although, he's stuffed if his company buys Facebook!

Comment: Facebook is just one word, so it'll become... a no-name company? (The Website Formerly Known as Facebook)

Comment: @Phylyp: Bang on! Good work!

Comment: @MikeSynnott - thank you. Also, welcome to Puzzling.SE, and we look forward to your continued participation!

Comment: Puzzling Stackexchange Question - Papa Sierra Quebec - Papsieque

Comment: @KYL3R: Close, but no cigar.

Comment: @sundar technically Facebook is already the website formerly known as "The Facebook".

Comment: @IanMacDonald [TanFox](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ff/61/ca/ff61ca6f9cb14ac2b91aba8dedaa4713.jpg) it is!

Comment: @Flater: I think you mean Tf. :(